# How to handle angularJS design time data?

Tags: angularjs

Silverlight had a nice feature ("design time data") that allowed one to indicate data for use in views which was only used at design time. This allowed a designer to work with fleshed out screens that looked realistic rather than just a skeleton.

(for a bit of background on this feature in Silverlight, here's a random [msdn post about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx))

Is there a similar approach for doing this in angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible w/ Angular.  Angular populates the views as it's processed, so you see the "skeleton" until it's done processing.  The design data you talk about would still have to be processed by Angular to be viewable.

You could always populate your scope with "design" data if you are waiting for API's to be built out, etc.  You could then work with the view html/css in Chrome dev tools or with any other browser tool set.  Not sure that's what you're looking for as it's still technically "runtime" development, but it might get you closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks nweg. "Runtime" is an acceptable compromise. How would one populate the scope without polluting the production code? I looked into Angular DI but it wasn't clear how/if I could override the $scope seen by the view? Do I instead have to build a complete set of mock controllers?

Comment: After thinking this over a bit I don't think I would personally do what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm not sure it's even possible.  One core reason AngularJS utilizes DI is to make is easily testable.  I've not see examples of people injecting mocks outside of testing.  Each controller scope is typically aligned with a specific view.  You would need at minimum a specific scope for each controller as you would not want to pollute the rootScope with this data. This would be a lot of work and I'm not sure how much you would gain from it.